# Making .bin File

Tags: grep, bin

This may be a stupid question, but I want a simpler way to replicate this technique used by Jon Erikson in the art of exploitation.  In it he fills a .bin file using a bunch of complicated stuff grepping for source code and so forth.

```
$ for i in $(head exploit_notesearch.c | grep "^\"" | cut -d\" -f2)
do
echo -en $i
done > shellcode.bin
```

This generates a file like so:

```
hexdump -C shellcode.bin
00000000  48 31 f6 48 31 d2 48 bb  2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68 11  |H1.H1.H./bin/sh.|
00000010  48 c1 e3 08 48 c1 eb 08  53 48 c7 c0 3b 11 11 11  |H...H...SH..;...|
00000020  48 89 e7 48 c1 e0 38 48  c1 e8 38 0f 05           |H..H..8H..8..|
0000002d
cat shellcode.bin
H1�H1�H�/bin/shH�H�SH��;H��H��8H��8
```

I don't know how to replicate this witchcraft, how can I make an exact replica using different commands?  I tried

```
cat > new.bin
x48x31xf6x48x31xd2x48xbbx2fx62x69x6ex2fx73x68x11x48xc1xe3x08x48xc1xe3x08x53x48xc7xc0x3bx11x11x11x48x89xe7x48xc1xe0x38x48xc1xe8x38x0fx05

cat new.bin
x48x31xf6x48x31xd2x48xbbx2fx62x69x6ex2fx73x68x11x48xc1xe3x08x48xc1xe3x08x53x48xc7xc0x3bx11x11x11x48x89xe7x48xc1xe0x38x48xc1xe8x38x0fx05

hexdump -C new.bin
00000000  78 34 38 78 33 31 78 66  36 78 34 38 78 33 31 78  |x48x31xf6x48x31x|
00000010  64 32 78 34 38 78 62 62  78 32 66 78 36 32 78 36  |d2x48xbbx2fx62x6|
00000020  39 78 36 65 78 32 66 78  37 33 78 36 38 78 31 31  |9x6ex2fx73x68x11|
00000030  78 34 38 78 63 31 78 65  33 78 30 38 78 34 38 78  |x48xc1xe3x08x48x|
00000040  63 31 78 65 33 78 30 38  78 35 33 78 34 38 78 63  |c1xe3x08x53x48xc|
00000050  37 78 63 30 78 33 62 78  31 31 78 31 31 78 31 31  |7xc0x3bx11x11x11|
00000060  78 34 38 78 38 39 78 65  37 78 34 38 78 63 31 78  |x48x89xe7x48xc1x|
00000070  65 30 78 33 38 78 34 38  78 63 31 78 65 38 78 33  |e0x38x48xc1xe8x3|
00000080  38 78 30 66 78 30 35 0a                           |8x0fx05.|
00000088
```

I hardly knew how to ask this question and am not aware of anywhere else to look.  I am grateful for any help.  Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific about exactly what you are trying to achieve. Are you just trying to convert ascii hex into binary?

Comment: I believe so.  I am trying to achieve the first .bin files format from the hex ascii string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is [`xxd`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html), which is normally used to get a hex dump of a binary file, but can also be used to perform a reverse hex dump, which is what you are trying to do.

Put your ascii hex into a file called `Input.txt`, without any of the `x`'s.

```
4831f64831d248bb2f62696e2f73681148c1e30848c1e3085348c7c03b1111114889e748c1e03848c1e8380f05
```

Next, run `xxd` with the flag `-p` for plain, and `-r` for reverse.

```
xxd -r -p Input.txt Output.bin
```

Now, the desired output should be in `Output.bin`.

```
hexdump -C Output.bin 
00000000  48 31 f6 48 31 d2 48 bb  2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68 11  |H1.H1.H./bin/sh.|
00000010  48 c1 e3 08 48 c1 e3 08  53 48 c7 c0 3b 11 11 11  |H...H...SH..;...|
00000020  48 89 e7 48 c1 e0 38 48  c1 e8 38 0f 05           |H..H..8H..8..|
0000002d
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of xxd but missed the remove \x part.  Was freaking me out.

Comment: @WhiteMask, You're welcome. Just remember the type of knowledge you are trying to learn is very dangerous, so use it wisely. :)